# Why is expo eject not working to eject expo application?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to eject my app build with expo using `expo eject` but I am getting some error I don't understand. Using expo eject I wasn't even asked what sort of app I want to eject to like expokit or regular react native. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Error after running expo eject]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run this with wsl it will work for you. currently there is a dependency on some gnu coreutils like cp so this command won't run on windows, there is an open issue to handle this and it will likely be resolved soon. if you'd like to help, here's the issue: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1827

Comment: So is there no way to eject expo app in windows?

Comment: yes, you can use wsl to eject or some other shell environment with gnu utils available